# BinarySearchTree finding closest value that is between certain values

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have a `Binary Search Tree` and I need to get the **closest higher** and **closest lower** and the closest lower has to been between 5 and 9 (meaning either higher than 5 or lower than 9).

Lets say I have a `Node` with ID 125, the **closest higher** number to that Node is 127, but it also has to be between 5 and 9 so `Node´ with ID 130 would be the one that I am looking for.

Here is the Binary Tree that I am working with:

[image]

This is how I am finding the closest higher at the moment:

```
Node currentNode = null;
int currentNodeID;
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;    

public Node closestHigherValue(Node root, double target, int low, int high) {
    min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    closestHigherHelper(root, target, low, high);

    if(currentNodeID < (int) target) return null;
    return currentNode;
}

public void closestHigherHelper(Node root, double target, int low, int high){
    if(root==null)
        return;

    if(Math.abs(root.ID - target) < min && root.ID >target){
        min = Math.abs(root.ID-target);
        currentNodeID = root.ID;
        //If between numbers
        if(root.ID >= low && root.ID <= high) currentNode = root;
    }

    if(target < root.ID){
        closestHigherHelper(root.leftChild, target, low, high);
    } else {
        closestHigherHelper(root.rightChild, target, low, high);
    }
}
```

This works until a certain point.. Here I add all the Nodes that can be seen on the `Binary Tree picture` and start finding closest points to certain values and then once found, deleting them. (Delete works fine).

```
BinaryTree binaryTree = new BinaryTree();
binaryTree.add(130);
...

int[] IDArray = new int[]{125, 100, 120, 130};
for (int i = 0; i < IDArray.length; i++) {
    Node closestHigher = binaryTree.closestHigherValue(binaryTree.root, IDArray[i], IDArray[i]+4, IDArray[i]+9);
    System.out.println("Searching for" + IDArray[i] + " and Closest Value = "+ closestHigher.getID());
    binaryTree.deleteNode(binaryTree.root, IDArray[i]);
        }
```

And this returns me :

```
Searching for 125 and Closest value = 130   //Should be 130
Searching for 100 and Closest value = null   //Should be null
Searching for 120 and Closest value = 125   //Should be 125
Searching for 130 and Closest value = 125   //Should be 135 -- This one goes wrong
```

Since **closest lower** is similar there is no need to show that code and I can fix that later when this one is fixed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `while being inside boundaries (between numbers 5 and 9)` ?

Comment: Edited the question to answer that

Comment: I think you should update `min` only `if(root.ID >= low && root.ID <= high)`. For more help post [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should update `min` only if within "boundaries", so this:

```
 min = Math.abs(root.ID-target);
 currentNodeID = root.ID;
 //If between numbers
 if(root.ID >= low && root.ID <= high) currentNode = root;
```

should be

```
 //If between numbers
 if(root.ID >= low && root.ID <= high){
    currentNode = root; 
    min = Math.abs(root.ID-target);
    currentNodeID = root.ID;
 }
```